# Exportar aplicación de monorepo (pnpm)

Tags: php, laravel, nodejs, packages, ts

tengo un monorepo creado usando turborepo y pnpm con la siguiente estructura:

```
├── apps
│   ├── web
│   ├── docs
│   └── dash
├── packages
│   ├── ui
│   ├── tsconfig
│   └── tailwind-config
└── package.json
```

Donde `dash` es un proyecto de Laravel. ¿Hay alguna forma de enviarle a alguien el código de `dash` sin tener que pasarle el monorepo entero?

He probado a copiar la carpeta `dash` (sin `node_modules`) pero al ejecutarlo dice que no puede encontrar los paquetes `ui`, `tsconfig` y `tailwind-config`.